# Opengl 3.3 c++ runtime error 'vector subscript out of range'

Tags: c++, runtime-error, opengl-3

My program compiles just fine but when I try to execute it I get a strange error.
I have included pictures of the error.
Also I would like to mention that this source code is from an online openGL tutorial found here http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-2-the-first-triangle/

Error pictures:

http://postimage.org/image/i6ernf8d7/

http://postimage.org/image/dvywy86xf/full/

Here is my source code:

Fragment shader

```
#version 330 core

// Ouput data
out vec3 color;

void main()
{

    // Output color = red 
    color = vec3(1,0,0);

}
```

Vertex shader

```
#version 330 core

// Input vertex data, different for all executions of this shader.
layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;

void main(){

    gl_Position.xyz = vertexPosition_modelspace;
    gl_Position.w = 1.0;

}
```

shader.hpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <GL/glew.h>

GLuint LoadShaders(const char * vertex_file_path, const char * fragment_file_path){

    // Create the shaders
    GLuint VertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint FragmentShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    // Read the Vertex Shader code from the file
    std::string VertexShaderCode;
    std::ifstream VertexShaderStream(vertex_file_path, std::ios::in);
    if(VertexShaderStream.is_open())
    {
        std::string Line = "";
        while(getline(VertexShaderStream, Line))
            VertexShaderCode += "\n" + Line;
        VertexShaderStream.close();
    }

    // Read the Fragment Shader code from the file
    std::string FragmentShaderCode;
    std::ifstream FragmentShaderStream(fragment_file_path, std::ios::in);
    if(FragmentShaderStream.is_open()){
        std::string Line = "";
        while(getline(FragmentShaderStream, Line))
            FragmentShaderCode += "\n" + Line;
        FragmentShaderStream.close();
    }

    GLint Result = GL_FALSE;
    int InfoLogLength;

    // Compile Vertex Shader
    printf("Compiling shader : %s\n", vertex_file_path);
    char const * VertexSourcePointer = VertexShaderCode.c_str();
    glShaderSource(VertexShaderID, 1, &VertexSourcePointer , NULL);
    glCompileShader(VertexShaderID);

    // Check Vertex Shader
    glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    std::vector<char> VertexShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength);
    glGetShaderInfoLog(VertexShaderID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", &VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);

    // Compile Fragment Shader
    printf("Compiling shader : %s\n", fragment_file_path);
    char const * FragmentSourcePointer = FragmentShaderCode.c_str();
    glShaderSource(FragmentShaderID, 1, &FragmentSourcePointer , NULL);
    glCompileShader(FragmentShaderID);

    // Check Fragment Shader
    glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    std::vector<char> FragmentShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength);
    glGetShaderInfoLog(FragmentShaderID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &FragmentShaderErrorMessage[0]);
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", &FragmentShaderErrorMessage[0]);

    // Link the program
    fprintf(stdout, "Linking program\n");
    GLuint ProgramID = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(ProgramID, VertexShaderID);
    glAttachShader(ProgramID, FragmentShaderID);
    glLinkProgram(ProgramID);

    // Check the program
    glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_LINK_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    std::vector<char> ProgramErrorMessage( glm::max(InfoLogLength, int(1)) );
    glGetProgramInfoLog(ProgramID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);

    glDeleteShader(VertexShaderID);
    glDeleteShader(FragmentShaderID);

    return ProgramID;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glfw.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
using namespace glm;

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "shader.hpp"

int main()
{

    if( !glfwInit() )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n" );
        return -1;
    }

    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_FSAA_SAMPLES, 4); // 4x antialiasing
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR, 3); // We want OpenGL 3.3
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE); //We don't want the old OpenGL

    // Open a window and create its OpenGL context
    if( !glfwOpenWindow( 1024, 768, 0,0,0,0, 32,0, GLFW_WINDOW ) )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window\n" );
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        glfwSetWindowTitle( "Tutorial 01" );
    }

    // Initialize GLEW
    glewExperimental=true; // Needed in core profile
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
        return -1;
    }



    glfwEnable( GLFW_STICKY_KEYS );


    glClearColor(0.3f, 0.5f, 0.9f, 0.0f);

    GLuint VertexArrayID;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
    glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);

    // Create and compile our GLSL program from the shaders
    GLuint programID = LoadShaders( "vertex.shader", "fragment.shader" );


    static const GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = { 
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
         1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
    };

    GLuint vertexbuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data), g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);



    do{

        // Clear the screen
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

        // Use our shader
        glUseProgram(programID);

        // 1rst attribute buffer : vertices
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(
            0,                  // attribute 0. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
            3,                  // size
            GL_FLOAT,           // type
            GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
            0,                  // stride
            (void*)0            // array buffer offset
        );

        // Draw the triangle !
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3); // 3 indices starting at 0 -> 1 triangle

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

        // Swap buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers();

    } // Check if the ESC key was pressed or the window was closed
    while( glfwGetKey( GLFW_KEY_ESC ) != GLFW_PRESS &&
    glfwGetWindowParam( GLFW_OPENED ) );


    // Close OpenGL window and terminate GLFW
    glfwTerminate();

    // Cleanup VBO
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);

    return 0;
}
```

I don't have great experience with openGL and c++ so any advice if I missed something would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vector index on line 47 is out of range. Check that the size of your vectors are as expected when debugging.

Consider using `data()` instead of taking the address of the first element.

```
VertexShaderErrorMessage.data()
```

instead of

```
&VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]
```

However, if the vector is empty this will not solve your problem.

Comment: I had this same issue after recently updating my NVIDIA drivers.  Doing the above and casting my equivalent of VertexShaderErrorMessage.data() to GLchar* solved my problem.  Thanks.

Comment: To avoid casting, consider changing the vector to contain GLchar, the call to data will then return the needed type.

Answer (score 0):

Does your program run fine in Release mode?

My OpenGL program runs fine in release mode but it crashes with this assertion report in Debug mode. I bypassed the issue since I couldn't figure out what went wrong in the code...and I mean I spent a whole day on this issue. What I did is that I copied the project's attributes in the Release config to a new config which I named DebugNoHiccup. Then to make it fit for debugging, I disable code optimization to allow stepping through the code.